# How can I implement a circuit that simulates white noise on $n$ qubits?

Tags: qiskit, noise

I want to test an error model of the convex form
$$t \times \text{ideal_state} + (1-t)\times \text{noisy_circuit}.$$
In terms of density matrices, this would look like
$$t\rho_{\text{idealState}}+(1-t)\times\text{Identity}.$$
However, I can only implement circuits on the simulator where I want to test and no density matrices.

Comment: For $n$ qubits, are you wanting to implement this noise on a per-qubit basis, or a global basis?

Comment: Is [this](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.aer.noise.depolarizing_error.html#qiskit.providers.aer.noise.depolarizing_error) helpful?

Comment: Yes, the depolarizing error is exactly what I want. Only question for me remains, how do I apply it to a state which is represented not as a density matrix but as a circuit? Is there something like a get_densitymatrix() attribute in the qasm simulator similar to the get_statevector() atribute?

Comment: Differently stated, I prepare a circuit for a graph state. I want to apply the depolarizing noise channel to the density matrix of the circuit and then later apply gates and measurements to the resulting state. In the depolarizing_error function in Qiskit Aer I lack the possibility of giving the density matrix as an input and I don't know how to obtain the density matrix from my circuit.

Comment: I could imagine that converting the circuit first to a statevector and then passing it to (https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.DensityMatrix.html) might work. That way I should be able to construct the entire channel by hand but there must be a better way than this?